# How to generate a matplotlib colormap from from an image of a colour scale?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I took a screenshot of a colour scale I would like to use with matplotlib. What is a good/easy way I could generate a matplotlib colormap object from this image?

[image: colorbar screenshot]

Edit: Here's my attempt at this:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('pet_colourbar.png')
data = img.load()

# Loop through pixels and extract rgb value
rgb_colours = []
for i in range(img.size[1]):
    rgb = [x/255 for x in data[0, i]]  # scale values 0-1
    rgb_colours.append(rgb)

pet_cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(rgb_colours[::-1])  # reverse order

# Plot example gradient
gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))
plt.imshow(gradient, aspect='auto', cmap=pet_cmap)
```

[image: Matplotlib colorbar]

Comment: That's an interesting task. But did you try anything? What problem do you face? Of course you need to read that image in. You then need to get the colors from that image. Can you do that? If so, show the code for it, such that people can help you extend it. If not, why ask about a colormap if the problem occurs much earlier?

Comment: I'm sorry this wasn't a good question. I didn't want to reinvent the wheel and half expected there might've been a well-known built-in way (or third party package) to do this (but some some quick googling revealed nothing). I've added an example of what I wanted to achieve above.

Comment: Please explain clearly how the example fails to meet your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this: `LinearSegmentedColormap` allows to creates a color map from a list of colors. Hence, you have convert your img to such a list:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


img = imread('/path/to/img')

# img is 30 x 280 but we need just one col
colors_from_img = img[:, 0, :]

# commonly cmpas have 256 entries, but since img is 280 px => N=280
my_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_cmap', colors_from_img, N=280)
```

Then use the newly created cmap as usual:

```
y = random_sample((100, 100))
imshow(y, cmap=my_cmap)
```

Comment: @OP I just posted this, since I was curious about how one would create a custom color map from an image. Please make sure to [learn how to ask good questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting your next question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is more concise than the solution I came up with. I will try to write a better question next time. Again, sorry for the format. I didn't realise my question was considered too broad.